# Read new s3 file paths from spark streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-streaming

I'd like to use spark streaming to monitor a s3 directory and return the path of any new files that are added to that directory. Neither textFileStream nor fileStream seem to be able to do this. Is there actually a way to accomplish what I'd like to do?

Edit: Spark ver. 2.1.0

Comment: Spark version ?

Comment: @mrsrinivas spark 2.1.0

Comment: can you add the code which you have tried? make sure you have configured access and secret keys properly yo access s3 file system.

Answer (score 0):

It does this using s3a:// ; I have tests to prove it.

1. set up a big enough window to deal with delays in scanning the dir, and clean it up.
2. you can write straight into the destination "directory"; no need to write and then rename. If you do that: the files are copied and pick up the window.
3. don't try checkpointing there